# std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator with consistent path separation?

Tags: c++

I just noticed that `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` uses different path separateors (i.e. `/` vs `\`) depending on whether it's on Windows or Linux, is there a way to make it return paths with `'/'` to make it consistent across systems?

This is how I am getting the paths:

```
for(auto& path: fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir_path))
{
    // Skip directories in the enumeration.
    if(fs::is_directory(path)) continue;
    string path_str = path.path().string();
}
```

What I mean is, the contents of `path_str` will be different between the two OSs (because the separators will be different), I would like them to be the same. I could just replace them on the final string, but that uses more cycles than if I can instruct the stl to use '/' for everything isntead.

Comment: `uses different path separateors (i.e. / vs \)` How are you checking that?

Comment: `recursive_directory_iterator` enumerates directory entries, not paths. Where are those paths coming from?

Comment: `how I am getting the paths:` so you are inspecting with the debugger that the content of `path_str`? The assumption `fs::recursive_directory_iterator` uses / or \ is too far - you only know that `path.path().string()` uses them. Does `generic_string()` solve your question?

Comment: @Makogan What do you intend to do with the `path` strings? One solution might be to simply not convert the `path`s to `string`s in the first place. For instance, if you need to open the files after iterating them, `std::(i|o)fstream` can open a file given a `path` rather than a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your problem has nothing to do with `recursive_directory_iterator`, which iterates on `directory_entry` objects, not paths. Your confusion probably stems from the fact that directory entries are implicitly convertible to paths, so you can use them as such.

Your problem is really about `path::string()`, which, [as the documentation states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string), uses the *native* format (i.e. with a platform dependent separator). You would get the same problem regardless of how you get your path.

If you want to get `/` as the directory separator, use `path::generic_string()` instead to get the path in generic format.

```
for(auto& dir_entry: fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir_path))
{
    if(dir_entry.is_directory()) continue;
    string path_str = dir_entry.path().generic_string();
}
```